# Hyperopt spark 3.0 issues

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, hyperopt

I am running runtime 8.1 (includes Apache Spark 3.1.1, Scala 2.12) trying to get hyperopt working as defined by

https://docs.databricks.com/applications/machine-learning/automl-hyperparam-tuning/hyperopt-
spark-mlflow-integration.html

```
py4j.Py4JException: Method maxNumConcurrentTasks([]) does not exist
```

when I try to

```
spark_trials = SparkTrials()
```

Is there anything special I need to do to get this working?

Here is the cluster I am using

```
{
    "autoscale": {
        "min_workers": 1,
        "max_workers": 2
    },
    "cluster_name": "mlops_tiny_ml",
    "spark_version": "8.2.x-cpu-ml-scala2.12",
    "spark_conf": {},
    "aws_attributes": {
        "first_on_demand": 1,
        "availability": "SPOT_WITH_FALLBACK",
        "zone_id": "us-west-2b",
        "instance_profile_arn": "arn:aws:iam::112437402463:instance-profile/databricks_instance_role_s3",
        "spot_bid_price_percent": 100,
        "ebs_volume_type": "GENERAL_PURPOSE_SSD",
        "ebs_volume_count": 3,
        "ebs_volume_size": 100
    },
    "node_type_id": "m4.large",
    "driver_node_type_id": "m4.large",
    "ssh_public_keys": [],
    "custom_tags": {},
    "spark_env_vars": {},
    "autotermination_minutes": 120,
    "enable_elastic_disk": false,
    "cluster_source": "UI",
    "init_scripts": [],
    "cluster_id": "0xxxxxt404"
}
```

this is the code I am using
https://docs.databricks.com/applications/machine-learning/automl-hyperparam-tuning/hyperopt-model-selection.html

Comment: are you using DBR 8.1 or DBR 8.1 ML?

Comment: I believe 8.1, not ML. Did I miss that requirement somewhere?

Comment: yes, added this as an answer and link to docs

Comment: Are you attaching any additional libraries? This specifically looks like https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/pull/765

Comment: Hyperopt, sklearn , mlflow. Let me do this. I'll kill my cluster, recreate it with the json, then reinstall those three. I have not tried that as if yet.

Comment: rebuilt the cluster, reinstalled those three, and made sure the cluster UI says they are installed on the cluster. Am I crazy or something??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hyperopt is only included into the DBR ML runtimes, not into the stock runtimes. You can check it by looking into release notes for each of runtimes: [DBR 8.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/runtime/8.1#installed-python-libraries) vs. [DBR 8.1 ML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/runtime/8.1ml#python-libraries).

And from the [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/applications/machine-learning/automl-hyperparam-tuning/index.html):

> **Databricks Runtime for Machine Learning** incorporates MLflow and Hyperopt, two open source tools that automate the process of model selection and hyperparameter tuning.

Comment: I didn't think to look at the release notes for the runtimes thanks!

Comment: I just run this example: https://docs.databricks.com/applications/machine-learning/automl-hyperparam-tuning/hyperopt-model-selection.html on DBR 8.2 ML (I don't have 8.1 at hands), and everything just works.  Try 8.2 ML, or post bigger snippet of code

Comment: ML Runtime specifically contains popular ML libraries, and they are all tested for compatibility - that's why it exists

Comment: I'm using ML runtime 9 and am getting the same error as OP.